# How to query Multi-index, Multitype in mongoosastic?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch, mongoosastic

I am trying to query multiple tables which has multiple indexes and types but there is no documentation available on multi-index,multitype query in mongoosastic.

Refer this [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/multi-index-multi-type.html) trying to do this same thing but with mongoosastic query.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Please do the following to make it work.

Make sure you deleted the indexes:

DELETE request via postman for example: http://127.0.0.1:9200/{your_name}

Then in node JS Create a mapping like this:

```
var schema = new Schema({
    product_name: String,
    description: {
        type: String,
        es_type: 'multi_field',
        es_fields: {
            multi_field: { type: 'string', index: 'analyzed' },
            untouched: { type: 'string', index: 'not_analyzed' }
        }
    }
});
```

Finally you can query like this:

```
{
"query" : {
    "constant_score" : {
        "filter" : {
            "term" : {
                "description.multi_field" : "nog een testje"
            }
        }
    }
}}// to use other field, change the . after description
{
"query" : {
    "constant_score" : {
        "filter" : {
            "term" : {
                "description.untouched" : "nog een testje"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}